# Function or method to exclude parameters with null values in Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I want to pass three values and get result according to that using Dapper, but other attributes in that class automatically taking null values and i want to neglect those parameters.
Now I am just passing say param1 and trying to get result. However my object as param2 and param3

```
connection.Query<T>("Query statement", whereConditions)
```

The whereConditions is object with param1, param2 and param3. However the result use where clause from param which has values and ignore the nulls

[UPDATE]

Query

```
select ID, UserName, Screen, Url, LogAction from LogTable 
Where UserName = 'Joe' and Screen = 'edit' and LogAction = 'delete'
```

Now From the UI, I am not sure if I will receive Username or Screen or Action. I can get any one of them of all three. My query has to change accordingly

If I create an anonymus object

```
var whereConditions = new { UserName = "Joe", Screen = "edit" }
```

It works well but in case of another parameter I need to pass it as

```
var whereConditions = new { UserName = "Joe", Screen = "edit", LogAction = "save" }
```

So I need to understand How can pass the anonymous object as where condition.

Hope this help

Comment: What dapper plugin are you using? as far as I know Dapper doesn't have CRUD methods included

Comment: I have made correction in the question. Does it help? @AlexKrupka

Comment: What does `Query statement` look like?

Comment: sql query with table name only and where condition contains the parameters

Comment: Make a custom object for the parameters param (second visible parameter). So Query<Foo>( "Select * from Foo where Foo1 =@Foo1 and Foo2=@Foo2",new {obj.Foo1,obj.Foo2}). Though as @christiandev said withou a better look at the query and objects involved can't be more specific

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach (which would only work if blank criteria values can always be ignored, which is commonly the case when these values originate from a UI form) would be to always pass all three arguments but to construct a WHERE clause that skips blank values - eg.

```
select ID, UserName, Screen, Url, LogAction
from LogTable
Where (@UserName = '' or UserName = @UserName)
and (@Screen = '' or Screen = @Screen)
and (@LogAction = '' or LogAction = @LogAction)
```

then you would pass all three values, regardless of whether they were null / blank or not

```
return conn.Query<Result>(
    @"
        select ID, UserName, Screen, Url, LogAction
        from LogTable
        Where (@UserName = '' or UserName = @UserName)
        and (@Screen = '' or Screen = @Screen)
        and (@LogAction = '' or LogAction = @LogAction)
    ",
    new
    {
        UserName = userName?? "",
        Screen = screen ?? "",
        LogAction = logAction ?? ""
    }
);
```

If you wrapped this up inside a method with optional arguments such as this:

```
private IEnumerable<Result> GetData(
    string userName = null,
    string screen = null,
    string logAction = null)
{
    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    {
        return conn.Query<Result>(
            @"
                select ID, UserName, Screen, Url, LogAction
                from LogTable
                Where (@UserName = '' or UserName = @UserName)
                and (@Screen = '' or Screen = @Screen)
                and (@LogAction = '' or LogAction = @LogAction)
            ",
            new
            {
                UserName = userName ?? "",
                Screen = screen ?? "",
                LogAction = logAction ?? ""
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then you could make the calling code look quite natural for differing numbers of arguments - eg.

```
var joeData = GetData(userName: "Joe");
var joeEditData = GetData(userName: "Joe", screen: "save");
```

However, if you requests always have the three values (userName, screen and logAction) and you just want the null / blank values to be ignored then you can, of course, simply call

```
var data = GetData(request.UserName, request.Screen, request.LogAction);
```